# how to set navigation of backbutton in fragments in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am working on an app with 5 fragments, having one fragment named home fragment.
I want whenever I press the back button on any of the other fragments, it navigates to the home fragment only.
pls, suggest to me how can I do this.? the below code is provided for reference

```
val expensefragment = expenseFragment()
    val notesfragment = notesFragment()
    val forumfragment =  forumFragment()
    val printfragment  =  printFragment()
    val homefragment =  homefragment()

    setCurrentFragment(homefragment)

    val bottomNavigationview  = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)

    bottomNavigationview.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            (R.id.expensebar)-> setCurrentFragment(expensefragment)
            (R.id.notesbar)-> setCurrentFragment(notesfragment)
            (R.id.printbar)-> setCurrentFragment(printfragment)
            (R.id.forumbar)-> setCurrentFragment(forumfragment)
            (R.id.homebar) -> setCurrentFragment(homefragment)
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment)
        commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add the Fragment in back stack there are a lot a tutorials available which can help you to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

After **replace** and before **commit** call the following function

```
.addToBackStack(backStateName);
```

if you don't want to give name of stack , pass null or empty value. This function will create backstack as Intent does.

Comment: in the navigation bar it still shows the previous navigation bar and not changing